# list of tcp connections for particular port

Tags: linux, tcp, iptables, netstat

I need list of tcp connections made where client has particular port 
for example :
from my linux server need to check if any connection is made with client by 8008 port of client within last two minutes..

Is this possible or I m looking for too much ..?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the *client* port? These are usually random.

Comment: yeah..need to trace port

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a job for `iptables`, not for a custom program, which makes your question a little off-topic here. I would advise you look around (e.g. on [sf]) for an appropriate firewall configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can read `/proc/net/tcp` for this, but it does not track history, so you need to poll it occasionally.  This will work so long as you don't mind "missing" some very short-lived connections.